# Wordpress How to register widget correctly

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I`m trying to register my widget in a theme.
Here is the code I have in my *functions.php* file:

```
require 'widgets/cat_widget_class.php';//my widget class
add_action('widgets_init', register_widget( 'Cat_Widget' ));
```

I see only this message on widgets admin page:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in         
C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\wordpress-blog\wp-
includes\plugin.php on line 888

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in 
C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\wordpress-blog\wp-
includes\plugin.php on line 906

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, 
no array or string given in 
C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\wordpress-blog\wp-includes\class-
wp-hook.php on line 298

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\wordpress-blog\wp-
includes\plugin.php:888) in 
C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\wordpress-blog\wp-
includes\pluggable.php on line 1210
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `register_widget` does not have a return value, so trying to use it as the second parameter for `add_action` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below code for register widget

```
function Cat_register_Widget() {
        register_widget( 'Cat_Widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'Cat_register_Widget' );
```

Comment: Welcome! Happy to Help :)